# pycurl returns much higher APPCONNECT (SSL handshake) time than command-line curl

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, libcurl, pycurl

I'm using pycurl to measure the response times for a website. According to the curl [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html), curl provides the following six times:

```
An overview of the six time values available from curl_easy_getinfo()

curl_easy_perform()
    |
    |--NAMELOOKUP
    |--|--CONNECT
    |--|--|--APPCONNECT
    |--|--|--|--PRETRANSFER
    |--|--|--|--|--STARTTRANSFER
    |--|--|--|--|--|--TOTAL
    |--|--|--|--|--|--REDIRECT
```

When I run the following python script the APPCONNECT time - which corresponds to the SSL handshake - is consistently much higher compared to the command-line:

```
import pycurl
import certifi
import logging

def retrieve_url(url):
    """
    Retrieves the requested url and records the response time.

    :param url: the url to retrieve
    :type url: string
    :return: A tuple of response times per exchange type if the request was successful, False otherwise
    :rtype: tuple/boolean
    """
    rvale = False
    try:
        curl = pycurl.Curl()
        curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
        # curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, "C:/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt") <-- same performance
        curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)  # set url
        curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, lambda x: None)
        curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
        curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)
        curl.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
        curl.perform()
        # Time from start until name resolving completed
        # https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME.html
        nlookup_time = curl.getinfo(pycurl.NAMELOOKUP_TIME)
        # Time from start until remote host or proxy completed.
        # https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME.html
        connect_time = curl.getinfo(pycurl.CONNECT_TIME)
        # Time from start until SSL/SSH handshake completed
        # https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME.html
        appconnect_time = curl.getinfo(pycurl.APPCONNECT_TIME)
        # Time from start until just when the first byte is received.
        # https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME.html
        pretransfer_time = curl.getinfo(pycurl.PRETRANSFER_TIME)
        ttfb = curl.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)
        curl.close()
        rvalue = (nlookup_time, connect_time, appconnect_time, ttfb)
    except pycurl, e:
        logging.error(str(e))

    return rvalue

print retrieve_url("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

For the above script the times I get are:

```
NAMELOOKUP: 0.047  
CONNECT: 0.063  
APPCONNECT: 0.344  
STARTTRANSFER: 0.406
```

From the command line I get:

```
NAMELOOKUP:  0.004  
CONNECT:  0.017  
APPCONNECT:  0.049  
STARTTRANSFER:  0.161
```

The above times change very little between runs. The difference in APPCONNECT time is always an order of magnitude higher for pycurl.

So I try to figure out what is the reason for this overhead in pycurl? I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows 7, curl version is 7.52.1. I also tried curl 7.38.0 in Debian GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie) with very similar results, so it doesn't appear to be OS/version dependent.

Comment: How many times did you run this test?

Comment: @user1767754 about 100 times each (pycurl and command-line curl)

Comment: why you focus on `APPCONNECT`? In your benchmark, `pycurl` is much slower than command `curl` in every states. I think it may because of the communication between python and C-extension module.